# NullPointerException on JSONArray initialized in background thread

Tags: java, android

I'm writing an android app I use a background thread to pull a JSONArray from a web service. I then need to interact with that JSONArray inside the main activity. Here's what I'm doing now:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
JSONArray stories;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new getAll().execute();

 //   try {
        System.out.println("stories.length());
//  } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    //  e.printStackTrace();
    //}



}
```

And the background thread:

```
    private class getAll extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, JSONArray> {
    private static final String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/CalibServer/webresources/storypkg.story/";
    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(Void... params) {

         //set up client and prepare request object to accept a json object
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
        httpget.addHeader("accept", "application/json");

        HttpResponse response;

        String resprint = new String();

        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            // Get the response entity
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            if (entity != null) {
                // get entity contents and convert it to string
                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                String result= convertStreamToString(instream);
                resprint = result;
                // construct a JSON object with result
                stories =new JSONArray(result);
                // Closing the input stream will trigger connection release
                instream.close();
            }
        } 
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) {System.out.println("CPE"); e.printStackTrace();} 
        catch (IOException e) {System.out.println("IOE"); e.printStackTrace();} 
        catch (JSONException e) { System.out.println("JSONe"); e.printStackTrace();}

        System.out.println("FUCKYEAHBG: " + resprint);
       // stories = object;
        return stories;
    }
```

My problem is that I'm getting a NullPointerException at the call to

```
System.out.println("stories.length());
```

It's acting like a didn't initialize the stories array, but should't that have been taken care of by the background thread (at the line: stories =new JSONArray(result); ) before that call is ever made?

I have a feeling this is because of the threading - perhaps there is another step I have to take to update the main activity after the AsyncTask runs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't rely on `stories` to be initialized when a *separate* Thread that runs **parallel** to the UI Thread initializes and updates `stories`.

> perhaps there is another step I have to take to update the main
>   activity after the AsyncTask runs?

[`onPostExecute()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) of the AsyncTask. Do whatever UI updates you need there. Since `getAll` is already a private inner class, you have full access to the Activity. You already return `stories` off to that (unoverriden) method, so this should be a minor change.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute (JSONArray stories)
{
  //use the now initialized stories
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're initializing the variable in a background thread. That means that the line

```
System.out.println(stories.length());
```

is executed in parallel with the code initializing the variable. That thus means that there is a huge chance that the background thread has not had the time to initialize the variable yet when this line is executed.

Your code is similar to the following situation: you have an empty cup in front of you, and ask someone to go make some coffee and to fill your cup. And immediately after asking, you start drinking. There will be no coffee inside the cup, obviously.

Re-read the android documentation on how to execute asynchronous tasks.